# Executing Python code lines in Cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I must precise that I don't clearly understand the relation between Cygwin and Python. I've seen tutorials of programmers launching a Python script in Cygwin with the following line:
python "file path"

I think that this line makes python build and run that script. My question is:
is it possible to directly write "print ("Hello World") " in Cygwin ?
By the way, are the three arrows (>>>) used to designate a Cygwin Shell input line?

Many thanks in advance!
Nicola

Comment: Yes, open an *interactive interpreter session* using simply `python` in the shell. This is frequently referred to as a REPL - read, evaluate, print loop.

Comment: Yes, doing `python <file>` will execute a python script. You can also type just `python` to open the interpreter. The `>>>` at the start of each line is python's doing -- all it says is this is a line. If you were to type `if True:` you will notice that the `>>>` turns into a `...` since you are now indented.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Cygwin site, you can find the answers to all of your questions.

Cygwin provides a collection of tools that give functionality similar to a Linux distro on Windows. Cygwin also provides substantial POSIX API functionality. When programmers launch their python scripts using Cygwin, they are using the tools provided within the Cygwin library.

To  avoid spoon-feeding while still answering your question, go into Cygwin and test it for yourself. What happens when *you* enter that command within Cygwin? Once you see the result, if you have any other questions, comment them on here.